# How to stop particle flipping when I move camera view by using C# scripting in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles

I am going to make cloud by using Unity particle.
But particles are flipped 180 degree when I move camera view.
I want to prevent this act by using C# scripting.
(I already prevent this by checking "Allow Roll", But want to prevent this using C# scripting, with uncheck "Allow Roll")
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVhlx.png)

Comment: _"But particles are flipped 180 degree when I move camera view. I want to prevent this act **by using C# scripting**"_ - just nest your emitter in a child object and apply a 180° to the parent.  No code required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.